# Sorting Unbounded Chechkbox Column in Datagridview Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

Hi I was looking for 2 days I didn't find anything working
I Have booklist datagridview that is binded in the database and has one checkbox column that is unbound and another dgv for storing the check rows in the booklist.

so when i checked one row in booklist it will store in the another dgv so when i sort the it out check state will not be remove

```
 Private Sub BooksDataGridView_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles BooksDataGridView.CellFormatting
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In BooksDataGridView.Rows
        If row.Cells("Edit").Value = False Then
            row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 41, 75)
        Else
            row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen
            row.Cells(0).Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen
        End If

    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        Dim tid = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        Dim sid = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        Dim type = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        For j As Integer = 0 To BooksDataGridView.RowCount - 1
            If BooksDataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value = tid And BooksDataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value = sid And type = "Book" Then
                BooksDataGridView.Rows(j).Cells("Edit").Value = True
                BooksDataGridView.Rows(j).Cells("stat").Value = 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'BooksDataGridView.Sort(BooksDataGridView.Columns(20), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
End Sub
```

Cell formatting keeps the check state by looping in the another dgv

now my problem I want to sort out the checked rows to the top of the book list

ex.

```
|    Book Title          Author  |
|☐ Harry Potter 1    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 2    J.k Rowling|
|☐ Harry Potter 3    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 4    J.k Rowling|
|☐ Harry Potter 5    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 6    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 7    J.k Rowling|

To

|    Book Title          Author  |
|☑ Harry Potter 2    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 4    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 6    J.k Rowling|
|☑ Harry Potter 7    J.k Rowling|
|☐ Harry Potter 1    J.k Rowling|
|☐ Harry Potter 3    J.k Rowling|
|☐ Harry Potter 5    J.k Rowling|
```

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f7d221cd-cebc-4582-aa6f-383c5767b4f2/sorting-an-unbound-column?forum=winformsdatacontrols) seems relevant.

Comment: I just found the answer
I add to a column that bind in the database that hold the check state 
when i check that row send to dbase as 2 

then in cell formatting if status = 2 then check all checkbox
I bind the column so it can be sorted

Comment: You can do that but it is not appropriate to add data to the database that doesn't belong there.